# Combine unknown number of named lists with the same key names

Tags: r

I have a list that may contain 2 or more named list, e.g.:

```
mylist <- c(list(a = "a1", b = "b1"), list(a = "a2", b = "b2"), list(a = 3, b = 3))
```

Since I know there are always two key names named a and b, I would like to query a and b, so that a would return:

```
> "a1" "a2" 3
```

b should return a list

```
> "b1" "b2" 3
```

None of the other existing solutions fit my purpose, as all of them are about merging two lists. However my input as warpped in c() can contain multiple lists.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compare the list names with `==`

```
unlist(mylist[names(mylist) == 'a'], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "a1" "a2" "3" 

unlist(mylist[names(mylist) == 'b'], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "b1" "b2" "3"
```

---

If you want output in lists separately, we can use `split` :

```
split(mylist, names(mylist))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to a two column data.frame and then use the `subset` or other ways to modify the output

```
out <- stack(mylist)
```